# Why does trying to save a URL with a stored procedure only insert a point?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

What I want is to save the url of an image, as I have seen the URLs are saved with two or four diagonals depending, so they are not taken as special characters and I already try those two ways, sending my URL string with more than one Diagonal attached.

I have debugged and followed the insertion process and all the way always carries the URL the additional diagonals, except at the time of inserting because the only thing that is saved in the URL field is a "."

The address goes in this way in the whole process `"..//..//../images/images/Logo.png"`, in its defect it goes with four diagonals but in no way is saved correctly.

The URL should go after the last pipe |, but only one point is seen.

[image]

Insert Code:

```
#region EMPRESA
    #region insertar Empresa
    public string insertarEmpresa(int idEmpresa, string nombre, string rfc, string direccion, int codPostal, string idEstado, string telefono, string colonia, string pais, string ciudad,int tipoS,string immex,string logo, int idUser, string ip)
    {
        establecerConexion();
        string result = "";
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader read = null;
            comando = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertarEmpresa", conexion);
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@idEmpresa", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idEmpresa;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@nomEmpresa", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nombre;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@rfc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rfc;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@direccion", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = direccion;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@codPostal", SqlDbType.Int).Value = codPostal;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@estado", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = idEstado;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@telefono", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = telefono;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@colonia", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = colonia;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@pais", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pais;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@ciudad", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ciudad;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@tipoS", SqlDbType.Int).Value =tipoS;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@immex", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = immex;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@logo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = logo;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@idUser", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idUser;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@ip", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ciudad;
            conexion.Open();
            read = comando.ExecuteReader();
            if (read.HasRows)
            {
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    result = read.GetValue(0).ToString();
                } return "1";
            }
            else return "1";

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            return "2";
        }
        finally
        {
            if (comando != null)
                comando.Dispose();
            conexion.Close();
        }

    }
    #endregion
```

The code of store procedure:

```
USE [DBSIADANA]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_InsertarEmpresa]    Script Date: 02/16/2017 12:33:38 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_InsertarEmpresa]
(
    @idEmpresa int,
    @nomEmpresa varchar(max),
    @rfc varchar(max),
    @direccion varchar(max),
    @codPostal int,
    @estado varchar(50),
    @telefono varchar(30),
    @colonia varchar(max),
    @pais varchar(50),
    @ciudad varchar(50),
    @tipoS int,
    @immex varchar,
    @logo varchar,
    @idUser int,
    @ip varchar(50)

 )
As
Begin
    Declare
    @idCiudad int,
    @idEstado int,
    @idPais int

    set @idCiudad = (Select idCiudad from DBSGICE.dbo.cCiudad where nomCiudad like '%'+@ciudad+'%')
    set @idEstado = (Select idEstado from DBSGICE.dbo.cEstado where nomEstado like '%'+@estado+'%')
    set @idPais = (Select idPais from DBSGICE.dbo.cPais where nomPais like '%'+@pais+'%')

    If exists(Select idEmpresa from DBEMPDEV.dbo.tEmpresa where idEmpresa=@idEmpresa)
        Update DBEMPDEV.dbo.tEmpresa Set nomEmpresa=@nomEmpresa,direccion=@direccion,colonia=@colonia,codPostal=@codPostal,idCiudad=@idCiudad
        where idEmpresa=@idEmpresa
    Else
        Insert into DBEMPDEV.dbo.tEmpresa (nomEmpresa,rfc,direccion,codPostal,idEstado,telefono,colonia,idPais,idCiudad,immex,logotipo,principal)
        values (@nomEmpresa,@rfc,@direccion,@codPostal,@idEstado,@telefono, @colonia, @idPais,@idCiudad,@immex,@logo,0)
        SET @idEmpresa=(SELECT TOP 1 idEmpresa FROM DBEMPDEV.dbo.tEmpresa ORDER BY idEmpresa DESC);
            Insert into DBSIADANA.dbo.tSistemaEmpresa(idEmpresa,idTipoSistema)values(@idEmpresa,@tipoS)

    Insert Into DBSIADANA.dbo.tLogEmpresa Values(GETDATE(), @idUser, 3, @ip, CONVERT(varchar(10),@idEmpresa)+' | '+@rfc)

End

GO
```

Comment: You can reduce columns, and put you stored procedure here, for faster finding root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show us your stored procedure you're calling, but from the symptoms described, I'm *guessing* that you've probably defined a parameter in that stored procedure as `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` - *without* specifying a **length** for that string.

In SQL Server, if you *omit* the length, the strings will default to a system-given length - in the case of **parameters** for a stored procedure, that length is **exactly one character**.

So `VARCHAR` is identical to `VARCHAR(1)` and thus accepts only **one character** long strings - everything else is silently truncated.

The moral of the story: you should ***ALWAYS*** (no exceptions!) define an **explicit length** with your `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` (and also `CHAR` and `NCHAR`) datatypes!

Change your `VARCHAR` to something like `VARCHAR(100)` (or whatever length makes sense in your scenario) and you should be fine